# Haskell: Efficient way to bitwise cast String to Integer?

Tags: haskell

What's the most efficient way to cast `String` (or `ByteString`) to an integral type bitwise, for example:

```
smallEndianStringToInt32 :: ByteString -> Int32
smallEndianStringToInt32 str = 
    case str of
      [a,b,c,d] -> shiftL d 24 .|. shiftL c 16 .|. shiftL b 8 .|. a
      _         -> 0
```

In C we can simply do it like this, really low-cost:

```
char* some_string = "....";
int32_t x = *(int32_t*)some_string;
```

But the former implementation (`smallEndianStringToInt32`) doesn't look as fast as the C code.

How can this be done? (Or it actually IS as fast?)

Comment: and what are you even trying to do in C ? Maybe be it's fast, but what is the purpose ? testing the first character of the string ? if so, you should consider testing the first character of your string, instead of "bitwise casting string to integer".

Comment: @StephaneRolland I thought such code is very common for deserialization. E.g. Storing/Loading an int into/from a file.

Comment: maybe, in this case, should you ask for the the fastest way to deserialize integer in Haskell.

Comment: If you need fast binary serialization, use Data.Binary. Otherwise, look inside it for the implementation of e.g. putWord32le and getWord32le.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for, but like the other commenters, I'd recommend you clarify what you're *actually* trying to do, as this is very non-idiomatic Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.ByteString.Internal
import Foreign.Storable
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Ptr
import Data.Word (Word32)

main :: IO ()
main = withForeignPtr fptr $ \ptr -> do
    i <- peek $ castPtr (ptr `plusPtr` off)
    print (i :: Word32)
  where
    PS fptr off len = "A\0\0\0"
```

As should be painfully obvious, this code is quite susceptible to segfaults, for example.

Comment: This code obviously produce correct result, but doesn't seem to be so effecient, as it involves allocations. ... Anyway, I guess I'd better use `Data.Binary`.